# New microphone not working on laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, microphone, hp

I got a new [Tracer Screamer](https://en.tracer.eu/microphone-tracer-screamer) microphone today for my laptop and when I plugged it in, my audio stopped working and the only audio input was from my laptop's original mic. I fixed the issue with the audio not playing when plugged in with the help of another post, now it plays sounds instead of just being silent, but still, the microphone is not working.

It does not show up in device manager:

[image: audio input and output in device manager]

[image: audio, game and console in device manager]

or in the sound control thing:

[image: sound recording]

[image: sound playing]

The new microphone is just not there, in the screenshots, its my Bluetooth headphones (f9) and other things that are basically part of the laptop(?) when i lug the microphone in, it reckognizes me and tells me that it is now plugged in, but the sound doesn't work and whenever I try to record an audio recording it just records it with the normal laptop mic

I looked at some tips on youtube and google, in most of them i would have to enable the mic in device manager or in the sound part in settings, but the mic doesn't show up there.

here's more info about my laptop if it helps:

DESKTOP-0S255KE

Windows 10 Pro

version: 21H2

.

**updates**

I tried doing settings-bluetooth and devices-add device-bluetooth/everything else, and the mic didn't show up there either.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Your screenshots have more than a single audio device. Some of the text is not in English

Comment: Welcome to the community. When clarifications are asked, testing suggested etc. best not to answer in a comment, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1769347/edit) your question instead - I did it now for you so you can delete those comments. That way all the relevant info is readily available. SE sites aren't discussion boards, but question/answer sites, so they work differently. I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/tour) to learn how these sites work.

Comment: Your microphone connects with a traditional 3.5mm plug and if your laptop has single connecter for external audio (AKA combo pòrt) then you CAN'T use it just like that. You need a audio I/O Y splitter and connect the microphone to the corresponding "mic in". What you already did to overcome what should be obvious as the normal and expected behavior with combo ports (designed for headsets+mic just like phones or tablets) may have to be undone now.

Comment: Just an example: https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256804278287467.html?spm=a2g0o.ppclist.product.26.6502AWHFAWHFbf&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21EUR%21%E2%82%AC%200%2C77%210%2C55%20%E2%82%AC%21%21%21%21%21%40211b4cf716767581008552659e99b6%2112000029259868640%21btf&_t=pvid%3A79a1db68-55bd-42c6-b279-3a4cd5beb330&afTraceInfo=1005004464602219__pc__pcBridgePPC__xxxxxx__1676758101&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt&_randl_shipto=US (microphone goes to red, simple headphones/headsets goes to green)